# How can I disable SSH KeychainIntegration in OS X Mavericks?

Tags: macos, ssh, keychain

I'm having some issues with SSH KeychainIntegration in OS X Mavericks.  I've tried poking around Apple's support site, but haven't seen anyone having my issue.  I *have seen* lots of people who seemingly don't know how to use SSH that well, so I decided to try another community.

First, my configuration is working.  I am able to use my key pair and ssh to hosts as I need to, with my credentials being cached in the agent.  I am able to see my cached credentials via "ssh-add -l", as expected.  I am prompted to input my password by an OS X-style dialog, with a checkbox that says "Remember password in my keychain".  I usually ignore this checkbox, but when I check it, I do see my key stored in the keychain.  This key stored in the keychain is seemingly never used, however, since I have a password on it.  At least that's what I've gleaned from various things I've read.  When I enter my password into the dialog, and the key is cached in the agent, I successfully connect, but not before being told "Saving password to keychain failed".  Seeing this error message is what led me to investigate further; I don't like getting an error every time I connect.

Things get interesting when looking at the manpage [SSH_CONFIG(5)](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man5/ssh_config.5.html).  Two options for dealing with the keychain exist, specific to Apple:  AskPassGUI, and KeychainIntegration.  You're able to toggle these in ~/.ssh/config, and doing so yields some interesting results.

Setting AskPassGUI to no, you'll no longer be prompted with an OS X-style dialog, instead an input text line in your terminal.  No biggie.  But if you do this, then ssh-agent will not cache your credentials.  This is plainly broken, and frustrating because I could easily live with the text prompt if the credentials were cached.

Setting KeychainIntegration to no, ssh throws a hard error, as follows:

```
~/.ssh/config: line 11: Bad configuration option: KeychainIntegration
~/.ssh/config: terminating, 1 bad configuration options
```

My question, simply, is this:  Is there a way to actually disable OS X Keychain Integration for SSH?

Comment: Nice question, I don't have an immediate answer, but hope with the votes it has, it will pop up on someone's radar. I can confirm the bug on my build of OS X with just a one line config file - setting the value to yes or no fails as described.

Comment: A point of clarification:  I only receive the message "Saving password to keychain failed" when ssh-add successfully caches credentials.  I *don't* see it on every connection attempt, which is how it reads, when I re-read it.  With cached credentials, it simply connects quietly, as you would expect.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on the source code for the current version of SSH that's shipping with Mavericks (located [here](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/OpenSSH/OpenSSH-186/openssh/)), it appears that the functionality of the config option `KeychainIntegration` has not yet been implemented. I'm making this assumption based on the contents of [openssh/readconf.h](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/OpenSSH/OpenSSH-186/openssh/readconf.h), which does not reference the `KeychainIntegration` option. It does, however, reference the `askpassgui` option. Checking the "keywords" struct in that file does indeed show that the `keychainintegration` option is not present (which in turn implies that the `oBadOption` (NULL) op code would be returned).

Another clue implying that the functionality you desire is not implemented in the way the man page specifies is the file: [openssh/keychain.c](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/OpenSSH/OpenSSH-186/openssh/keychain.c). The source code actually shows that the [`defaults`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/defaults.1.html) system (i.e., Property List files) is being used to store settings related to `KeychainIntegration`. Specifically, lines from the `store_in_keychain` function reference KeychainIntegration:

```
/* Bail out if KeychainIntegration preference is -bool NO */
if (get_boolean_preference("KeychainIntegration", 1, 1) == 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Keychain integration is disabled.\n");
    goto err;
}
```

Here is the corresponding `get_boolean_preference` function. Note that it's using [`CFPreferencesCopyAppValue`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFPreferencesUtils/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CFPreferencesCopyAppValue) to obtain a boolean from the "org.openbsd.openssh" application identifier:

```
#if defined(__APPLE_KEYCHAIN__)

static int get_boolean_preference(const char *key, int default_value,
int foreground)
{
int value = default_value;
CFStringRef keyRef = NULL;
CFPropertyListRef valueRef = NULL;

keyRef = CFStringCreateWithCString(NULL, key, kCFStringEncodingUTF8);
if (keyRef != NULL)
    valueRef = CFPreferencesCopyAppValue(keyRef,
        CFSTR("org.openbsd.openssh"));
if (valueRef != NULL)
    if (CFGetTypeID(valueRef) == CFBooleanGetTypeID())
        value = CFBooleanGetValue(valueRef);
    else if (foreground)
        fprintf(stderr, "Ignoring nonboolean %s preference.\n", key);

if (keyRef)
    CFRelease(keyRef);
if (valueRef)
    CFRelease(valueRef);

return value;
}

#endif
```

This might imply that you can disable the `KeychainIntegration` functionality for yourself by performing this defaults command:

`defaults write org.openbsd.openssh KeychainIntegration -bool NO`

or to set it for all users:

`sudo defaults write /Library/Preferences/org.openbsd.openssh KeychainIntegration -bool NO`

Comment: You dug deep, and I appreciate it.  I tried setting `KeychainIntegration` to `NO` via `defaults` as you suggested.  `ssh` then behaves as if I'd set `AskPassGUI` in `~/.ssh/config` -- no credentials are cached, and I'm prompted for the passphrase all the time.  Less than useful.  Still, I think you've answered the question, and the answer is, simply, "It can be disabled, but it isn't fully implemented, and you probably won't like the results."

Comment: Thank you so much I was searching all over to find an answer to this. Since I have a custom .zshrc file that I port between mac and linux it was driving me nuts that keychain was taking control of managing ssh-agent and the added keys.